# Compute Euler characteristic of paraboloid

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Let $\Sigma$ be the surface parameterized by $f(u,v)=(u\cos{v}, u\sin{v},u^2)$ for $u\geq 0$ and $0 \leq v \leq 2\pi$. Let $\Sigma_{r}$ the protion of the surface with $0 \leq u \leq r$. What is $\chi(\Sigma_{R})$ ?

The problem asked previously about the geodesic curvature, which I have wrong for some mistake in the computation. I do not know if it's useful here, but my gess is that it's not.

Comment: $\Sigma_r$ looks a lot like a disk to me. What is the Euler characteristic of a disk?

Comment: If it's a disk, then it's 1. But, I m confused. Are you saying that $u$ is fixed? Because I was understading $\Sigma_{r}$ as the paraboloid but finite, this is, no higher than a certain hight.

Comment: No, no, I'm talking about $0\le u\le r$. That gives you the portion of the paraboloid you're talking about. But it's parametrized by the disk of radius $r$ in the $uv$-plane, which, as you said, has $\chi = 1$.

Comment: Ok, I see what you say. But, the parabolid is not "filled". Why do we consider disks instead of the surface of the parabolid? I am still confused. Sorry if it's an easy question, I am a beginner with this part of differential geometry

Comment: Why are you talking about filling the paraboloid? I mean the two-dimensional disk of radius $r$ in the $uv$-plane.

Comment: The thing is that I am not understading the exercise, I think. We have a paraboloid, and "cut" it at a certain hight. Then you are saying that $\Sigma_{r}$ parameterized by the disk of radius r. I understand that parameterization, what I don't see is why now the surface $\Sigma_{r}$ is the disk, instead of the paraboloid cut. Does it make sense?

Comment: I said the disk *parametrizes* the paraboloid. They are topologically the same because you have what's called a diffeomorphism from one to the other. If this is too confusing, just triangulate the paraboloid shape. It's just as easy as triangulating the disk.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Thank you for your help